# Gathering information about the event loop in a web browser

Tags: javascript

The following code displays in the console the difference between the requested interval and the actual interval.

Does this enable us to say anything meaningful about the length of the event loop (in broad terms, I am not very interested in individual ticks)? If so, what?

```
var start, interval;

interval = 2000; // ms

function go() {
    start = performance.now();

    setTimeout(function() {
        var end = performance.now();
        console.log(end-start-interval);
        go();
    }, interval);
}
go();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. All it tells you is something about the accuracy of the timer mechanism. Event processing takes as long as it takes.

Comment: Well it tells me *something*. For example, if I call `alert('foo')` then the time logged to the console is significantly larger because the alert blocked the event loop.

Comment: Right, but that's my point. There is no single "length" to an event loop. The browser dispatches to code, and the code runs until it returns. That might take almost no time, or it might take a lot of time.

Comment: @Ben: To me that sounds like saying the knowledge you were scheduled late tells you you were scheduled late. That's precisely zero information *on top of what you already know*.

Comment: @Jon An alert could be replaced by a function that performs badly under some as-yet-unknown circumstances. In that case the performance characteristics are unknown beforehand and might be uncovered by such a check? I say "might" because there will be an interaction between `interval` length and the magnitude of the performance degradation. But if `interval` is sufficiently small in comparison to the expected performance deviation, something meaningful might be gained?

Comment: @Pointy The timer mechanism is "accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now

Comment: The `performance` API gives you very accurate time information, but that's not the same thing as the browser's `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` mechanism.

Comment: `setTimeout` does a best effort within the limitations of the single-threaded event loop. The control case can be determined by running the same code on a control page with nothing running on it.

Comment: If your question is whether measuring elapsed time by checking two bracketing timestamps measures the intervening execution time of some code, then the answer is "yes"; that's not how I interpreted your question upon first reading however. Yes, you can time the execution of code by checking timer values; that's how jsperf works.

Comment: @Pointy, no I misinterpreted your comment. But with a control, you can understand the accuracy of the timer machanism (setTimeout here) beforehand, and take this into account.

Comment: To some extent, perhaps, though it's going to vary on a system-to-system basis. Maybe that's what you're trying to do: see if it's possible for code to adapt to the client environment?

Comment: For node.js there's this package that says measures "event loop lag": https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-loop-lag - Here's its source code: https://github.com/pebble/event-loop-lag/blob/master/event-loop-lag.js

Comment: @Pointy I am not particularly interested in absolute numbers (although if I could get them, I'd like that), but an indication of relative stress would be good.

Comment: I would imagine that in the context of the browser, the behavior that a mechanism like that would measure is likely to vary over time, potentially widely, based on activity on the page and other tabs, background operating system activity, etc.

Comment: Agreed. And I don't necessarily need to know the cause. I *would* like to know when performance of my app is degraded.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

One reason for that is: the callback will be scheduled to run once the executor is idle. Which it might be "all the time", except the one case where another callback might happen to get scheduled just before yours and take over execution for however long it wants to.

In this scenario your callback could be delayed for an unbounded amount of time, but that tells you nothing about the "steady state" situation.

Comment: Okay, point taken, I think. The likelihood of a longer interval is increased as the "stress" on the event loop increases though, so some general information is gained? How could you get a decent reading of the event loop duration?

Comment: @Ben: Sure it would. And you could keep stats on this to eventually estimate mean delay and variance, but it's not clear how that information would be useful.

Comment: Reasoning: if the performance of an app is known-good with a reading  upto 50ms, and is known-poor with a reading over 50ms delay in the setTimeout, then when 50ms is reached consistently you can say something about the user experience. This is potentially useful information. Clearly, the event loop could simply be blocked completely, meaning that nothing is ever communicated about the steady state of the application - in such a scenario the application has frozen. But this does not necessarily invalidate the approach. Meaningful information might be available over a range of  conditions.

Comment: ...or is there a fundamentally better approach to gauging the client-side performance of a web application?